# PayPal WebHook Verification in PHP

Tags: paypal, paypal-webhooks

Referencing the answer here: [PHP verify Paypal webhook signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61041128/php-verify-paypal-webhook-signature)

Is this still the working solution for today (Jan '22)? Curious why it says on github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK that this package is deprecated? (and archived)?

Answer (score 1):

This is how i verify the call from PayPal to my webhook with PHP:

```php
$success = (
    openssl_verify(
        data: implode(separator: '|', array: [
            $httpPayPalTransmissionId,
            $httpPayPalTransmissionTime,
            $webhookID,
            crc32(string: $rawRequestBody),
        ]),
        signature: base64_decode(string: $httpPayPalTransmissionSignature),
        public_key: openssl_pkey_get_public(public_key: file_get_contents(filename: $httpPayPalCertUrl)),
        algorithm: 'sha256WithRSAEncryption'
    ) === 1
);
```

Comment: It should be pointed out that the value of the PAYPAL-CERT-URL header should be validated to be a paypal.com domain. Otherwise, an attacker (given knowledge of the webhook-id) could construct a fake payload signed with a selfhosted cert.

Answer (score 1):

I have just done this for **wordpress**, feel free to alter for your needs.

make sure you create your webhook in your dashboard with the events you need, and get the ID from it to use.

Create a function to generate auth tokens for paypal:

```
function paypal_access_token() {
    $clientID = 'PAYPAL_CLIENT_ID';
    $clientSecret = 'PAYPAL_SECRET_key';
    
    $auth = base64_encode( $clientID . ':' . $clientSecret );

    $cacheKey = 'PAYPAL_ACCESS_TOKEN_' . $clientID;
    $token = get_transient($cacheKey);

    if ($token === false){
        $body = [
            'grant_type' => 'client_credentials',
        ];
        $credential_post = wp_remote_post( 
            'https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token', 
            array(
                'method' => 'POST',
                'headers' => array(
                    'Authorization' => "Basic $auth",
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                ), 
                'body' => urlencode_deep( $body ),
            ) 
        );

        $result = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $credential_post );

        $token = json_decode($result, true);
        set_transient($cacheKey, $token['access_token'], ($token['expires_in'] - 60));
        $token = $token['access_token'];
    }

    return $token;
}
```

then create a verify event function:

```
function paypal_verify_webhook($args){
    $token = paypal_access_token();

    $paypal_post = wp_remote_post( 
        'https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/verify-webhook-signature', 
        array(
            'method' => 'POST',
            'headers' => array(
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                'Authorization' => "Bearer $token",
            ), 
            'body' => wp_json_encode( $args, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES ),
        ) 
    );
    
    $paypal_response = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $paypal_post );
    
    if ( !is_wp_error( $paypal_response ) ) {
        return $paypal_response;
    }
    
    return false;

}
```

and finally the webhook file itself:

```
$requestBody = file_get_contents('php://input');

if(!$requestBody) {
    exit();
} 

$headers = getallheaders();
$headers = array_change_key_case($headers, CASE_UPPER);


if(
    (!array_key_exists('PAYPAL-AUTH-ALGO', $headers)) ||
    (!array_key_exists('PAYPAL-TRANSMISSION-ID', $headers)) ||
    (!array_key_exists('PAYPAL-CERT-URL', $headers)) ||
    (!array_key_exists('PAYPAL-TRANSMISSION-SIG', $headers)) ||
    (!array_key_exists('PAYPAL-TRANSMISSION-TIME', $headers)) 
)
{
    exit();    
}

$webhook_id = 'WEBHOOK_ID_FROM_DASHBOARD';
$args = array(
    'auth_algo' => $headers['PAYPAL-AUTH-ALGO'],
    'cert_url' => $headers['PAYPAL-CERT-URL'],
    'transmission_id' => $headers['PAYPAL-TRANSMISSION-ID'],
    'transmission_sig' => $headers['PAYPAL-TRANSMISSION-SIG'],
    'transmission_time' => $headers['PAYPAL-TRANSMISSION-TIME'],
    'webhook_id' => $webhook_id,
    'webhook_event' => json_decode($requestBody)
);

$verify_webhook = paypal_verify_webhook($args);
$verify_status = json_decode($verify_webhook, true);


if( isset($verify_status['verification_status'] ) && $verify_status['verification_status'] === "SUCCESS"){

    $data = json_decode($requestBody, true);

    if (isset($data['event_type'])) {
        $event_type = $data['event_type'];

        switch ($event_type) {
            case 'CHECKOUT.ORDER.COMPLETED':
                // Do Stuff...
                break;
            case 'PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED':
                // Do Stuff...
                break;
            // Add more cases etc...
            default:
               // Do Stuff...
                break;
        }
    }
    http_response_code(200);
    exit();

}
else{
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That SDK is deprecated and not maintained. There is no support for it.

There are two supported ways to verify a webhook, either post it back to an API endpoint, or verifying the cryptographic message signature yourself.

- [Verifying a message signature](https://developer.paypal.com/api/rest/webhooks/#link-messagesignature)
- [Posting back to PayPal](https://developer.paypal.com/api/webhooks/v1/#verify-webhook-signature-post-request-body)

Neither document is specific to PHP, but has the information necessary to adapt into your own implementation in any language.

Comment: I think this answer is only partially correct. The "Verifying a message signature" does NOT have the necessary information to adapt to PHP as the "magic" is happening inside a Java library like: What are the possible values for the signature algorithm, etc.

Comment: There are PHP libraries for the same operations, see for example this recent question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75566384/how-to-validate-paypal-signature-validation . I have not implemented this in PHP myself.

Comment: I agree with you in terms, that there might be other answers out there, which cover this specific question. But here you state, that the documentation covers everything, which is wrong. The documentation unfortunately only poorly covers how to do that.*

Also the question you are referencing is exactly that: A question, not an answer and even not correct regarding the code, because the algo is hardcoded there.

If you haven't implemented it yourself in PHP why do you even answer to a question about this regarding PHP?

Comment: Because it is important to not use the deprecated SDK, and useful to be aware of the posting back to PayPal as an alternative. The details of a PHP implementation are left as an exercise to someone else, and they are welcome to answer here