# is there any Adaptive payments in alipay like paypal?

Tags: php, payment-gateway, alipay

As subject says I want to know if Alipay's api allow you to have Adaptive Payments like paypal where two different recipients get the payment in their Alipay accounts?

Here is the discussion I found for paypal
[Paypal API - Can we transfer money to multiple accounts in a transaction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460993/paypal-api-can-we-transfer-money-to-multiple-accounts-in-a-transaction)

What I want is a similar API system for Alipay if it exists

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried searching for an answer and read their api document which can be downloaded from global.alipay.com, according to it there doesn't seem to be an adaptive payment system like paypal and to confirm this I also sent them an email, their reply was the same

Thanks